# WordPress files downloading instead of executing on the server

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress files are downloading instead of executing on the server. I have tried changing the server but that does not solve the issue. I am sure it is happening from my WordPress files as the hosting runs other WordPress files smoothly.

I wish I could could provide the code but that isn't needed. Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: @Toby: Not providing the link as the site is compromised.

Comment: From what I understand of your question, you attempt to browse to a page but instead of the page displaying, it is downloaded; is that correct?

Comment: @Toby: Yes. You are right.

Comment: File extensions are all `.php` and each file starts with `<?php` without leading spaces, carriage returns etc?

Comment: @mudasobwa: Here is the link to my site:
www.inspuratesystems.com/natalid

Comment: @mudasobwa: Check my question again.

Comment: This is web-server (Apache?) issue. You should check that php extension is loaded and configured. Check for `.htaccess` file in your home directory, share it’s content (I bet substituting it with wordpress default version would solve the issue.)

Comment: @FahadUddin What was the last thing you did on the site. The white page of Death is a common WordPress issue. it usually happens after you install a theme, plugin or update Wordpress and find that the theme/plugin are no longer supported.

Comment: @FahadUddin Are you sure that the other sites you are hosting share the same IP? I'm convinced that the PHP isn't running on the server. Please try uploading a phpinfo.php file (read my answer below) and verify it is working

Answer (score 0):

I have only seen this happen when:

**1) PHP is turned off or not installed on the server**

**2) The server needs to be reset**

3) File names are not correct

4) The redirect script is not redirecting as it should

5) Links are not valid

The good news is most of these can be solved by you/your host. Call your host to ask them for help on verifying the PHP install/process. If everything is good (for instance, if you have another site on the same server that is working fine) then you need to verify file names. As this is WordPress and the file names are all pretty standard this isn't exactly likely but make sure there are no unwanted spaces and the file names are "something.php". With WordPress you may see a bunch of parameters passed through the URL so "something.php?blah=blah" Is fine too (no space between php and ?).

Check the link you are clicking. The file names might be good but the link may be bad. It might be as simple as fixing all the link URLs. From what I recall of WordPress, there is a built in method of linking to pages within the same WP site. I believe these are all based off the URL in the database so you may want to verify the URL in the database/config file to verify WP is sending them to the correct place. If they are not stored in the database and are instead, coded directly into the content, you may have to manually update every link to the correct URL.

Finally, if it is script or wordpress related you may want to consider a fresh WordPress install. The good thing about WordPress is all the good stuff is in the data base:

1) Make a backup of the data base

2) Trash your WP install completely

3) download and install new WP with desired plugins and themes

4) Restore database

If the last step breaks the server again, check URLs within the database: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Your Host can usually help in backing up and restoring WP databases. Even godaddy (who does not support it) will often help you walk through the process (you really want to call the hosting team. As an ex-godaddy employee, those guys are the experts).

If this isn't enough information, please provide a link to the site. It will allow me to do some quick troubleshooting to determine the overall issue.

**EDIT:** Help for verifying php install

Create a php file with the following contents:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And upload it to your site

This will make information about your PHP install easily accessible

Note: DO NOT LEAVE THIS FILE UP PERMANENTLY AND DO NOT POST A LINK PUBLICLY, YOU DO NOT WANT RANDOM PEOPLE ON THE INTERNET ACCESSING THIS INFORMATION

If you can access the file and it loads up a bunch of information in a purple (I believe it is purple) table, your PHP install is up and running. If the file just downloads like the rest, contact your hosting provider.